# What is a better "back" label for a step by step process: Previous or Go Back?

Tags: terminology

We have a step by step process in which the user clicks "Next" to continue on with their step. I know that "previous" is the obvious label, but wouldn't "Go back" be a bit more friendly/human? Next/Previous sounds like controls for a music player, which this is not it. This is a step process to installing a system.

Would another alternative be "Go back/continue"?

Answer (score 2):

Be as contextual as you can be. Button labels should indicate clearly where the user will go if he/she clicks it.

As for the options you suggested, "Go back" sounds too absolute, it feels more like a "cancel", "never mind". "Previous/next" is OK, just not the most clear it can be.

So if your system is a step by step flow, use labels like **"last step"** and **"OK! Next step"**.

You can go further and label them with the steps number/name. **"Back to step 2"** or **"back to install options"**.

Comment: I was going to say this, so no reason to do it and +1 for you, specially for the last part

Answer (score 1):

"Previous" is obvious choice here as "Go Back" gives a sense of feel that app is asking/highlighting user to go back where going back to previous screen should be option not mandatory!!